# When you attach an entity in EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a DbSet and and DbContext in EF Core:

```
public interface IMyContext : IDisposable
{
    DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync();
}

public class MyContext : DbContext, IMyContext
{
    public MyContext (DbContextOptions<MyContext > options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    public async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        return await SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken.None);
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
    }
}

public enum OrderStates
{
    Open,
    Running,
    Suspended,
    Closed,
    Cancelled
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerDesc { get; set; }
    public OrderStates State { get; set; }
}
```

here how I create the context:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyContext")),             services.AddHangfire(options => options.UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyContext")));
    services.AddOptions();
    services.Configure<MySettings>(options => Configuration.GetSection("MySettings").Bind(options));
    services.AddMvc().AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
    services.AddSignalR();

    services.AddSingleton<IMyContext, MyContext>();
    services.AddSingleton<Erp, Erp>(); // this references MyContext
}
```

when the application starts I show this a Page with this code:

```
public class OpenOrdersModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly MyContext _context;

    public OpenOrdersModel(MyContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IList<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        Orders = await _context.Orders.Where(x => x.State == OrderStates.Open).ToListAsync();
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public List<Order> ListOrders { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        foreach (var order in ListOrders)
        {
            order.State = OrderStates.Running;
            _context.Orders.Attach(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        return RedirectToPage();
    }
}
```

But when I try to Attach the order I get the following error:

> The instance of entity type 'Order' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value 'Id:1002' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

The error itself is pretty clear, what I don't understand is how I might have "attached" such an entity. In all my code there no *attach* instruction but the above one.

I don't know where to look at because I really don't know how I could have attached that record.

Comment: Look here `Orders = await _context.Orders.Where(x => x.State == OrderStates.Open).ToListAsync();` and [Tracking vs. No-Tracking Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking)

Comment: I really didn't find that page. Now I understand my error. Thanks